# Why are my Class member variables going missing in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, member-variables

I made a class. I think that I create a member variable named "myTup" in the initializer/constructor. I try to make sure that I actually did create myTup  by making the following call right at the very end of the initializer:

```
assert(hasattr(self, 'myTup'))
```

However, later, the interpreter says that my instance/object doesn't have a member variable named "myTup."

Where did myTup go? Come back to me... please Q_Q

The following script is only long due to all of the little debug statements. Without the debugging, it's actually quite short and simple.

### Code:

```
import inspect
def lineno():
    # Returns the current line number in our program.
    return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno

class DemoClass:

    def __init__(self, initial_data):

        went_in = False # did not enter the if-elif-else block

        if isinstance(initial_data, str):
            print('line number:', lineno())
            t = tuple(initial_data)
            self = DemoClass(t)
            went_in = True        
        elif isinstance(initial_data, DemoClass):
            print('line number:', lineno())
            self = initial_data
            went_in = True
        elif isinstance(initial_data, tuple):
            print('line number:', lineno())
            self.myTup = initial_data
            went_in = True
        else:
            print('line number:', lineno())
            went_in = True
            assert(False)

        assert(hasattr(self, 'myTup'))
        print('line number:', lineno())
        print('went_in:', went_in)
        print('myTup:', self.myTup)

    def __str__(self):
        return "DemoClass" + str(self.myTup)

obj = DemoClass("s")
print(obj)
```

### Output:

```
line number: 13
line number: 22
line number: 31
went_in: True
myTup: ('s',)
line number: 31
went_in: True
myTup: ('s',)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  [... truncated / abridged ...]

  File "E:/awesome_folder_name/missing_member_var.py", line 36, in __str__
    return "DemoClass" + str(self.myTup)

AttributeError: 'DemoClass' object has no attribute 'myTup'
```

Comment: Why do you redefine `self`?

Comment: The line `self = DemoClass(t)` is your issue. Your code wants to overload `__init__()` to deal with different types for initial_data (which is fine), but don't try to recursively call `__init__` from itself, and never try to overwrite `self` anywhere inside an object or its methods.

Comment: The whole `line_no`,`went_in` inspection code is wack, it just confuses things. You don't need an if-else ladder for handling multiple types for `initial_data`.

Comment: You want to allow `DemoClass.__init__()` to be called with three different possibilities for `initial_data` : a string, a tuple, or an existing instance of DemoClass. This last one is weird: are you trying to copy or clone an object? (use copy()). There's no point in doing what you do: wrapping the given instance of DemoClass inside a new instance of DemoClass. You couldn't access its `initial_data` except by writing `obj. initial_data.initial_data`

Comment: You might find [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can't replace the instance created in `__init__`. The following replaces only the `self` reference in the `__init__` method, **not the previous instance that `self` was bound to**:

```
if isinstance(initial_data, str):
    # ...
    t = tuple(initial_data)
    self = DemoClass(t)
```

When `__init__` returns, the `obj = DemoClass("s")` line still bound the first instance, not the one you created with your recursive call. That first instance has no `myTup` attribute.

You'd have to call `self.__init__(t)` instead to operate on the same instance:

```
if isinstance(initial_data, str):
    # ...
    t = tuple(initial_data)
    self.__init__(t)
```

This then calls `__init__` again, with the same instance bound, and thus will set `myTup` on the right object.

Note that I'd avoid using recursion here. There is no need, just set a tuple in the different branches and then assign `myTup` at the end:

```
def __init__(self, initial_data):
    if isinstance(initial_data, str):
        initial_data = tuple(initial_data)
    elif isinstance(initial_data, DemoClass):
        initial_data = initial_data.myTup
    elif not isinstance(initial_data, tuple):
        raise ValueError('Invalid data')

    self.myTup = initial_data
```

If you must control what instance is returned when trying to create a new one with `DemoClass()`, then you can only do so with the [`__new__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__); it is responsible for producing the instance in the first place (after which the default implementation would call `__init__` on that new instance).